# Functions of sufficient statistics - are also they sufficient?

Tags: probability, statistics

Are $1-1$ functions of sufficient statistics (for a given parameter) also sufficient for that parameter?

For example, if $X$ is a sufficient statistic for parameter $p$, is $\log(X)$ also sufficient for $p$?

Comment: There's even a bit stronger statement: if $T$ (sorry, $X$ is reserved for the sample) is sufficient and $T = h(S)$, then $S$ is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course. In your example, for a given $f$, and assuming that $X$ has the
distribution depending on a parameter $\theta$, and with $T(X) = \log X$:

$$
E[f(X)|T(X), \theta] = f(\exp(T(X))= 
E[f(X)|T(X)]
$$
does not depend on $\theta$. Hence $T(X)$ is a sufficient statistic.

Comment: Thanks - thought so, but wanted confirmation!

Comment: of course, this is the very trivial example of complete statistics. But one has to start somewhere!

Comment: Wait, complete or sufficient? Does this 1-1 transformation also hold for completeness? Sorry, just want to clarify. Thanks!

Comment: Or, to say that completeness holds under 1-1 transformations as well.

Comment: hum sorry, I mistook both terms. this is sufficient statistics I was talking about!